# R - How to manipulate all subsets of a dataset at once

Tags: r, dataframe, split

is it possible to manipulate the column of a dataset which is already split into a number of subsets? The problem is that the code looks pretty useless if applied to another functions.

```
> df <- split(d08,d08$kraj_zn)
> df$BA$min <- min(df$BA$EQ_INC20)
> df$TT$min <- min(df$TT$EQ_INC20)
> df$TN$min <- min(df$TN$EQ_INC20)
> df$NR$min <- min(df$NR$EQ_INC20)
> df$BB$min <- min(df$BB$EQ_INC20)
> df$ZA$min <- min(df$ZA$EQ_INC20)
> df$KE$min <- min(df$KE$EQ_INC20)
> df$PO$min <- min(df$PO$EQ_INC20)
```

**EDIT:**

What I want to do is manipulate `df$min` from somewhat like this:

```
 > . ROK . . . kraj_zn min
 > 1 2008 . . . BA -100
 > 101 2008 . . . TT -100
 > 201 2008 . . . TN -100
 > 301 2008 . . . NR -100
 > 401 2008 . . . BB -100
```

To this:

```
> . ROK . . . kraj_zn min
> 1 2008 . . . BA -399
> 101 2008 . . . TT -120
> 201 2008 . . . TN -1
> 301 2008 . . . NR -25
> 401 2008 . . . BB -67
```

So the values of `df$min` would represent a min value based on `df$kraj_zn`.

Comment: You could also use a `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` and `transform` as so:

```
lapply(df, transform, min=min(Q_INC20))
```

Answer (score 0):

**dplyr** is great for these kinds of per-group operations. You don't provide a fully reproducible example, but the equivalent to your code would probably be:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- d08 %>%
  group_by(kraj_zn) %>%
  summarize(min = min(EQ_INC20))
```